# StackPanel visibility not updated when dependency property changed

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

I'm currently developping an universal app in C#/XAML with MVVM (not MVVM Light) and I have trouble for the XAML part.

I'd like to display one or another `StackPanel` when a dependency property changed in my ViewModel. I think the code speaks for itself.

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <!-- Some content -->
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <!-- Some another content -->
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the definition of the dependency property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyProperty",
    typeof (bool),
    typeof (MyViewModel),
    new PropertyMetadata(true));

public bool MyProperty
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged(); // Implemented by ReSharper }
}
```

I guess you figure it out that `MyProperty` is a boolean that I convert into a `Visibility` via the converters. So, when `MyProperty` changed in the ViewModel, the view isn't updated.

I already tried to use the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property but it's not working. Also, I have no binding error and converters are working fine (I only see one `StackPanel` at the app launch).

Please keep in mind that I don't want to use the code behind part unless there is no other solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add the definition for your dependency property?

Comment: Do you notify of the property changed?

Comment: @AaronHawkins : Sure. I just edited the inital post.

Comment: @ChrisW. : could you be more specific please ?

Comment: [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged)

Comment: @ChrisW. yeah of course I implement the interface, and I call the `OnPropertyChanged()` method in the setter of my property.

Comment: You either implement INPC or dependency property, not both... i think in your scenario you only implement INPC and a regular property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly gave up and used the code behind part and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Are your `<StackPanel>`s part of some UserControl?  If not, why are you using `DependencyProperty`?

Your implementation is quite off as well.

Lets assume for a minute that this is not part of a Custom Control (correct me -- if I'm wrong, I will rewrite the solution)

So you have a ViewModel and you want to hook up some Properties to it.  You really don't need to implement DependencyProperty to do what you want to do, but I will entertain you by implementing it your way.

This is a sample ViewModel with 1 (one) property

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using System.ComponentModel;

// very simple view model
class MyViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 

    // register
    public static DependencyProperty FooterTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FooterTitle", typeof(string), typeof(MyViewModel),
         new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnFooterTitlePropertyChanged));

    // the actual property
    public string FooterTitle
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(FooterTitleProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(FooterTitleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // this will fire when the property gets change
    // it will call the OnPropertyChanged to notify the UI element to update its layout
    private static void OnFooterTitlePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyViewModel mvm = dependencyObject as MyViewModel;
        mvm.OnPropertyChanged("FooterTitle");
    }
}
```

---

To test out the code we will make a very simple XAML form

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding FooterTitle}" FontSize="48"></TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Test Property" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When you click on the button we will change the Textbox's Text

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    // create the view model
    MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;


        // set the text we initial want to display
        vm.FooterTitle = "default text";

        // set the DataContext of the textbox to the ViewModel
        tb.DataContext = vm;
    }


    // after the button is click we change the TextBox's Text
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // change the text
        vm.FooterTitle = "Test Property Has Changed.";

        // what happens is the Setter of the Property is called first
        // after that happens it launches the `OnFooterTitlePropertyChanged` event
        // that we hook up with the Register function.


        // `OnFooterTitlePropertyChanged` launches the INotifyPropertyChanged event
        // then finally the TextBox will updates it's layout
    }
}
```

---

At this point you can guess you really don't need the DependencyProperty and say why can't I just launch the INotifyPropertyChanged in the Setter instead?  Well you can and it is probably the prefer method.

If all these is part of a UserControl then I can see using a DependencyProperty then in the `OnFooterTitlePropertyChanged` event you can set the

```
name_of_textbox.Text = FooterTitle;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm looking for.
To be honnest, currently my `StackPanel`s aren't part of a custom `UserControl`, but they will be later (I'm at the early stage of developpement). Plus, I'd like to avoid the use of the code behind part, because it's an universal app and I don't want to copy/paste code. Of course, if there is any other solution, I will do as you said.

Comment: @Atlasmaybe There is no code behind (that was just to test out the VM).  That VM can be part of the shared project.  Replace the TextBox with your StackPanel and you will see once your Property changes it will launch your converter.  The example I coded was to get you into the right direction because your question and sample code makes very little sense.

Comment: I analysed your code and it's the same as mine : you have one simple VM with a DP, a simple View. The differences reside in the `OnPropertyChanged()` event launch and the `ButtonClickEvent` (which is part of the code behind of the page you created) that you use to change the property whereas mine is changed in the VM.
I appreciate the effort you gave to put me in the "right direction", but I don't think it would help if we have the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I think property name should be given with OnPropertyChanged method, like this;

```
public bool MyProperty
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { 
              SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); 
              OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty"); 
        }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged